# Python xml.etree.ElementTree raises ParseError if attrib value is integer

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am trying to parse an xml with few attrib values are integers. In such cases, python ElementTree class raise a ParseError

xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 120, col
umn 32

And here is my xml

```
<Rectangle
  leftTopX = 0
  leftTopY = 0
  rightBottomX = 20
  rightBottomY = 40
/>
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid this ParseError?

Modifying attrib values in below fashion would serve as a solution for my problem. But I have multiple xml files to parse. Changing attrib values would take more time.

```
<Rectangle
  leftTopX = "0"
  leftTopY = "0"
  rightBottomX = "20"
  rightBottomY = "40"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) parser - it's more forgiving in terms of well-formness. Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<Rectangle
  leftTopX = 0
  leftTopY = 0
  rightBottomX = 20
  rightBottomY = 40 />
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.rectangle
```

prints:

```
<rectangle lefttopx="0" lefttopy="0" rightbottomx="20" rightbottomy="40"></rectangle>
```

You may also use it with `lxml` parser (you'll need `lxml` installed):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
```

Hope that helps.